# How can I access subclasses from upper class in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 3 classes;

- 'Company' top class its subclass 'Department' its subclass 'DepartmentalUnit'
- I can access the values ​​of all classes from the 'DepartmentalUnit' class to the top class 'Company'

What I could not do and understand despite reading the document is that;;

- I cannot access other subclasses from the 'company' class

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    departments = relationship('Department',backref='company')


class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    department_name = Column(String)

    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'))
    departmentalunits = relationship('DepartmentalUnit', backref='department')


class DepartmentalUnit(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'departmentalunit'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,nullable=False)
    departmental_unit_name = Column(String)

    departments_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'))
```

The code from which I access the upper classes from the subclasses:

```
query = session.query(DepartmentalUnit)
instance = query.all()

for i in instance:
    print(i.department.company.name)
    print(i.department.department_name)
    print(i.departmental_unit_name)
```

The code I can't access other subclasses from the company class:

```
query = session.query(Company)
instance = query.all()

for i in instance:
    print(i.department.department_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your last query should be used differently:

- there is a typo in the name of the relationship: should be `departments` instead of `department`
- given that the relationship is 1-N, the result is a list, so you should iterate over children.

This should work:

```
query = session.query(Company)

for company in query.all():
    print(company.name)
    for dep in company.departments:
        print("  ", dep.department_name)
        for dep_unit in dep.departmentalunits:
            print("    ", dep_unit.departmental_unit_name)
```

Comment: I solved the problem by adding backref to relationsships. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I added a backref to relationships and now I can access all of them from the company. Not sure if it's a correct method? However, I am currently getting the return I want. I have no unanswered request yet.

Example solved:

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    departments = relationship('Department',backref='company',uselist=False)


class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    department_name = Column(String)

    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'))
    departmentalunits = relationship('DepartmentalUnit', backref='department',uselist=False)

class DepartmentalUnit(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'departmentalunit'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,nullable=False)
    departmental_unit_name = Column(String)

    departments_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'))


query = session.query(Company)
instance = query.all()

for i in instance:
    print(f"Company: {i.name}")

    print(f"Department: {i.departments.department_name}")

    print(f"Department Unit: {i.departments.departmentalunits.departmental_unit_name}")

    print( f"Report Category : {i.departments.departmentalunits.reportcategoryoftheunit.report_category_name}")
```